# How do Hestu's seed requirements scale?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Every time you use Hestu to upgrade your space, it costs more seeds for the next upgrade.

I was keeping my upgrade levels equal across the board, just looking for the cheapest to upgrade, but I now think that all 3 scale at different paces.

So just to see if I'm hallucinating or not, how does Hestu scale for his upgrades?

Something like:

Swords

- Lvl 1 - 1 seed needed
- lvl 2 - 2
- lvl 3 - 4
- [...]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Hestu's Korok seed scaling differs depending on which item slot you want to improve. [See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsCkp.jpg).

Here's how it goes if the image isn't clear:

| Weapons | Bows | Shields |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 | 4 |
| 8 | 8 | 5 |
| 12 | 12 | 10 |
| 17 | 17 | 10 |
| 25 | 25 | 10 |
| 35 |  | 10 |
| 45 |  | 10 |
| 55 |  | 15 |
|  |  | 15 |
|  |  | 15 |
|  |  | 15 |
|  |  | 15 |
|  |  | 20 |

All in all, you'll need 441 out of the 900 Korok Seeds to upgrade all of your stashes completely.

Comment: I wish SE would allows some sort of table markup.  There have been a few times where I would like to put my answer into a table.

Comment: **900** seeds? The completionist in me is crying.

Comment: @TimmyJim I know it's been over two years since your comment, but I've found [this generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and code blocks to be an effective workaround (_mea culpa_ if you use a screen reader)

Comment: @TimmyJim After 3~4 years, your wish has been granted!

Answer (score 10):

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzZf1.jpg) is from the official guide for the game and explains how many seeds are needed for each type of slot.

Weapon slots can be upgraded 11 times, bows slots can be 8 times, and shields 16 times.

To reiterate:

**Weapons:**

1. 1 seed
2. 2
3. 3
4. 5
5. 8
6. 12
7. 17
8. 25
9. 35
10. 45
11. 55

---

**Bows:**

1. 1 seed
2. 2
3. 3
4. 5
5. 8
6. 12
7. 17
8. 25

---

**Shields:**

1. 1 seed
2. 2
3. 3
4. 4
5. 5
6. 10
7. 10
8. 10
9. 10
10. 10
11. 15
12. 15
13. 15
14. 15
15. 15
16. 20